# Что за имя __detail в unordered_map.h?

Tags: c++, stl

Я решил узнать как реализована хеш-таблица в моей версии STL. Захожу в файл `/usr/include/c++/9/bits/unordered_map.h` и вижу там имя `__detail`:

```
namespace std _GLIBCXX_VISIBILITY(default)
{
_GLIBCXX_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_VERSION
_GLIBCXX_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_CONTAINER

  /// Base types for unordered_map.
  template<bool _Cache>
    using __umap_traits = __detail::_Hashtable_traits<_Cache, false, true>;
```

Что такое `_GLIBCXX_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_VERSION` и `_GLIBCXX_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_CONTAINER` ? В файле нет ни одной директивы `#include`. `__detail`, что это ?

Comment: namespace и макросы.

Comment: *"ни одной директивы #include"* Тогда видимо файл не самодостаточный, и работает только если его заинклудить после каких-то еще файлов.

Comment: я хочу понять как работает инструментальный цех, но не объясните мне что такое отвертка и  фреза?...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan намёки можно по-разному понимать, но если я правильно понял, то: если бы я не знал основ C++, я бы не пошёл в исходники STL. я бы задался вопросом что такое STL

Comment: @HolyBlackCat спасибо, разобрался, на этом этапе. Можете оценить ответ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это пространство имён, определённое в файле `bits/hashtable_policy.h`.

Comment: имена пространств имен на подобии `detail`, `impl`, `aux`, и т.д. используются для того, чтобы засунуть в них какие-то детали реализации и при этом не засорять "основное" пространство имен.

Comment: что касается _GLIBCXX_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_VERSION, то смотрите здесь: https://subak.io/code/ardupilot/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8/bits/c++config.h.html